# Wake on Lan only working if computer shut off recently

Tags: networking, shutdown, wake-on-lan

I set up WOL on my desktop so I can access some of the programs on it remotely when I need to without leaving it on. I tested it by turning the computer off and sending the magic packet from my laptop and it booted fine.

When I actually wanted to make us of WOL today, the computer wasn't booting. I got home, tried it again, and still nothing. I turned the desktop on and then off again, and then when I tried it again it worked..

Is there some kind of delay for how long the NAT card stays active after the computer is shut off? Why would WOL only work in a short time span after the computer shutting off?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities -

Modern computers have different levels of powered-off states ([sleep states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) - its possible that as time goes by your computer is going into deeper sleep states and disabling your network card - in which case you may be able to tweek it in the BIOS.

The other - from your post much less likely possibility might relate to how you are sending the WOL packet - is that WOL only works on the LAN or through an agent - it can't work directly through the wider Internet.  Thus NAT has nothing to do with the state,  but might imply accessing it from the wider Internet.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but I sent the packet using a website, so it shouldn't have mattered if I were home or not. I'll check my bios again for sleep states

Comment: Which website did you send the packet through ?  If the website was located on the wider Internet, it may be expecting the system to be on the LAN, using Javascript or somesuch to get the local PC to send an appropriate packet.  To the best of my knowledge a random computer on the Internet can not wake up a sleeping computer, even if it has all the information it would need to do so.

Comment: https://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/woli. The only outgoing request I see as a result of clicking the button is one to woli-ajax.php, so I think it is sending the request from the server

Comment: This functionality must require "Subnet Directed Broadcast" on your router (and upstream devices).  What router do you have, and do you know if it supports subnet directed broadcast.  Also, have you tried sending a WOL packet over the LAN directly?

Comment: I just have port 9 forwarded to the static ip of the computer. And I don't think that's the problem, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to send the packet through the  site